# A getter method that doesn't necessarily get a member's value?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, naming, convention

Say I have a C++ class that holds an array.

A member function of this class for example, could be to return the value at a certain index. I'm confident this would be considered a getter method.

However, how would you classify a similar function that instead simply returns a boolean based on whether or not the value **exists** in the array?

This function is 'getting' something but not necessarily a value from a member of the class. Would this still be considered a getter method?

Comment: What is a "getter method" in your book? Does it really matter if this thing is a getter method or not?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Exactly !

Comment: IMO: Getter methods return (get) the value, of a sub-object, stored inside of an object. This method, however, performs an operation on the data, and returns a result of such an operation, hence, I would not classify it as a getter method. Based on your description, any method, with non-`void` return type, would be considered getters, since they would, all, "get" something.

Comment: The name "getter" is usually used for functions that return the value of a member. Similarly, "setter" usually refers to a function that modifies a member. The primary use of these functions is to convince yourself that your interface is not exposing any internal implementation details even though it does.

Comment: Thanks all, happy with the new point of view, a lecturer of mine placed emphasis on the naming in this situation. Everyone seems to agree it's borderline trivial. Ty for the guiding comments.

Comment: Another thing to point out perhaps is that if there's value to "getter" functions which are implemented to simply return a member variable, one of them besides making it impossible to modify the variable outside the class is to be able to turn them into "non-getters" in the future. If you have a getter function like `sum()`, you might find it useful in the future to compute that on the fly instead of simply returning a member variable to, say, make the class require fewer locks for multithreading -- something like this (just one example reason).

Comment: ... whereas if the variable was exposed, then suddenly such a change would require modifying all the external code directly accessing that variable instead of just modifying the local implementation of that one "getter" function (which will no longer be a "getter" afterwards, and instead become like a "compute function"). "Getters" are very uninteresting functions and I think having many of them is a sign of potentially poor interface design, but they do have this merit when taken on their own where you can make them compute something in the future instead of simply returning a member's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really matter? Consider this interface:

```
struct Adder {
    Adder(int a,int b);
    int get_sum();
};
```

for the user of this class it should not matter at all whether implementation is this:

```
struct Adder {
    Adder(int a,int b) : a(a),b(b) {}
    int get_sum() { return a+b; }
private:
    int a,b;
};
```

or this:

```
struct Adder {
    Adder(int a,int b) : c(a+b) {}
    int get_sum() { return c; }
private: 
    int c;
};
```

The second does return a member and according to your definition it would be a "getter" method. The first does not, but does it mean that it is not a true "getter" method? Whether the method actually returns a member or something else is an implementation detail and should not matter to the caller, nor should it affect the name you give to the method.

Comment: I agree. A sound definition/description of interface functions should not depend on the implementation.